# Can pytest capture output from a doctest?

Tags: python, pytest, doctest

I'm running `pytest` with `--doctest-modules` and no other options.

I've got a `doctest` test that's failing, and I'm trying to debug the issue by adding `print()` statements to the underlying code.

Capturing output is working and displaying as expected for my regular (non-`doctest`) tests, but the `doctest` tests aren't showing stdout in my `pytest` output, even though I've got `print()` statements happening in there.

I could re-write my `doctest` as a non-`doctest` test in order to get those `print()` statements to flow through, but that sounds like an awfully roundabout thing to do.

Is there any way to tell `pytest` that I want it to capture output for `doctest`s too?

```
$ python --version
Python 3.7.2
$ pytest --version
This is pytest version 3.10.1, imported from /home/gene/.pythonz/pythons/CPython-3.7.2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytest.py
setuptools registered plugins:
  pytest-xdist-1.26.1 at /home/gene/.pythonz/pythons/CPython-3.7.2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xdist/plugin.py
  pytest-xdist-1.26.1 at /home/gene/.pythonz/pythons/CPython-3.7.2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xdist/looponfail.py
  pytest-pythonpath-0.7.3 at /home/gene/.pythonz/pythons/CPython-3.7.2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytest_pythonpath.py
  pytest-mock-1.10.0 at /home/gene/.pythonz/pythons/CPython-3.7.2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytest_mock.py
  pytest-forked-1.0.1 at /home/gene/.pythonz/pythons/CPython-3.7.2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytest_forked/__init__.py
  hypothesis-4.4.1 at /home/gene/.pythonz/pythons/CPython-3.7.2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/hypothesis/extra/pytestplugin.py
  flaky-3.5.3 at /home/gene/.pythonz/pythons/CPython-3.7.2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flaky/flaky_pytest_plugin.py
```

Comment: The easiest way is to print to stderr as `doctest` only captures stdout for comparison. `print('debug stuff', file=sys.stderr)` etc. Of course, you should still run `pytest -s` to capture the output.

Comment: I think this is also covered in [Capturing of the stdout/stderr output — pytest documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/capture.html#setting-capturing-methods-or-disabling-capturing)

Answer (score 2):

Turning my comment into an answer: the easiest way is to print to stderr as `doctest` only captures stdout for comparison. Example:

```
import sys


def greet(who):
    """Greet someone.

    >>> greet('world')
    'Hello world'

    >>> greet('fizz')
    'Hello fizz'

    >>> greet('buzz')
    'Hello buzz'
    """

    print('input:', who, file=sys.stderr)
    return f'Hello {who}'
```

Running the tests:

```
$ pytest --doctest-modules -sv
======================================= test session starts ========================================
...
collected 1 item                                                                                   

spam.py::spam.greet input: world
input: fizz
input: buzz
PASSED

===================================== 1 passed in 0.03 seconds =====================================
```